# How Service Container create object declared in services.yml?

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

Consider this code:

```
public function showActiveJobsAction($slug)
{
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
     $category = $em->getRepository('JobeetBundle:Category')->findBySlug($slug);
     if (! $category) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Category entity.');
     }

     $jobService = $this->container->get('job_service');
     $category = $jobService->populateCategoryByItsActiveJobs($category);

     return $this->render('JobeetBundle:Category:jobs.html.twig', array(
        'category'      => $category,
    ));        
}
```

job_service need JobeetBundle:Category repository to work. The repository is passed to service constructor. It's all defined in services.yml

So in this case I end up with two instance of JobeetBundle:Category repository class?

If yes how can I change my design to do it better?

Probably it's better to create code just like:

```
$jobService->getCatetoryWithActiveJobsByItsSlug($slug)
```

but I still wonder if container looks for object existance before create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a service from the container, by default, you get always the same instance. It is also the same instance when this service is injected into another one.

So you don't have two worry, you get only one instance of the service `job_service`.

Here is an extract from the [Symfony2 book, chapter Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html):

> As an added bonus, the Mailer service is only created once and the same instance is returned each time you ask for the service. This is almost always the behavior you'll need (it's more flexible and powerful).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In general, you wont get duplicate repositories (or services) in Symfony2 so no worries there.

This:

```
$jobService->getCatetoryWithActiveJobsByItsSlug($slug)
```

Is a better approach simply because it hides the entity manager/repository stuff from your controller.  You could (in theory at least) swap out the entire Doctrine2 engine with something else and still have your controller code work.